# Isn't the potential energy of a spring in SHM at equilibrium zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I was just solving some problems on SHM and there's a question which asked the PE of the body at equilibrium,

the question:

> A body of mass 2 kg suspended through a vertical spring executes simple harmonic motion of period 4s. If the oscillations are stopped and the body hangs in equilibrium, find the potential energy stored in the spring.

based on what I had  learned  PE at equilibrium is zero
but it turns out it's not always true
could anyone please explain the reason?
and whts the difference between the mean position and equilibrium position

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589369/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At equilibrium, the spring is elongated due to the force of gravity on the mass. So the PE in the spring is due to this elongation.

Equilibrium (in mechanics) means that all the forces are exactly balanced, i.e. net force is zero.

Comment: thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

The necessary condition for a particle to undergo SHM is that the potential energy should be minimum at the equilibrium point.

[image]

in this case if you free the particle, the particle will fall towards the surface of earth to minimize the potential energy.

Comment: Necessary, but not sufficient for SHM.

Comment: thanks for the reply

Comment: @BillN yeah but that was already known by the OP

Comment: most probably..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the zero of the potential energy wherever you like.  But at equilibrium, the gradient of the potential energy is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the question asks for the PE of *the spring*, not the PE of *the SHM system*. Thus you should be focusing on the spring. [ *Lesson:  read the question carefully and answer the question asked, not the question you think has been asked.*]

With PE, there is always the question "PE compared to what?"   That is, PE *always* must be defined with respect to some reference state. Think about gravitational PE.  Is it $mgh_1$ where $h_1$ is height above the table, or $mgh_2$ where $h_2$ is the height above the floor?  Which is your reference state?   Equivalently (and perhaps stated more generally), the only thing that has physical significance are PE differences.

In your case, there is implicit in the statement of the problem that there is a reference state *of the spring* somewhere.  The question is really "What is the difference between the PE of the current state of the spring and the PE of the reference state?"  The natural choice is the relaxed state of the spring: neither stretched nor compressed.   What is the  PE of the relaxed state?   One could say that we have the same problem:  PE compared to what?

A further implication of the fact that only PE differences are significant is that we are free to choose any particular state to be the reference state (as in $mgh$), and we are free to define the PE there as $PE = 0$.  The author has tried to sneak in the fact that he has made that choice by asking for the PE *stored* in the spring.

This is all a long winded   and hopefully useful way of saying:   the question is asking for the PE of the stretched spring where the relaxed spring has $PE = 0$.